# Translation of clout

Tags: translation

I can't find any good translation for the word clout, which, it seems to me, is a fairly relevant concept in terms of the way things work politically in China. In some context like this,

"Does the business leader really have the clout to influence those regulations?"

it means social ability, connections, or prestige which affords a special influence. [Clout](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clout)

Comment: jukuu has 36 example sentences for "clout"

Answer (score 2):

I found two examples when I looked it up in Collins COBUILD:

1. Mr Sutherland may have the **clout** needed to push the two trading giants into a deal...

> 萨瑟兰先生也许有**能力**促使两大贸易巨头达成协议。

2. The two firms wield enormous **clout** in financial markets.

> 两家公司在金融市场有非常大的**影响力**。

Hope these examples help :)

Answer (score 1):

How about 权力 or 影响力 or just 力量？

The two firms wield enormous clout in financial markets.
两家公司在金融市场有非常大的影响力。

Does he have any clout?
他有什么影响吗？

国际政治力量
international political power/strength/clout

Answer (score 1):

maybe 權勢

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000103700

roughly, 權 is power, and 勢 is influence:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=權](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%AC%8A)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=勢](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8B%A2)

Answer (score -1):

According to the Youdao Dictionary（有道词典），the word ‘clout’ means influence （影响力）